# MonoTouch: tab menu bar not working

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone app that uses a tab menu bar... works fine in the iPhone... when I change info.plist to iPad, the menu stops working.  Why?  and how do I fix it?

Comment: The right way to **solve** this is to write your own answer and then accept it. That way any other user that has a similar question will see that an answer is available and you'll get points for your own answer (it's perfectly ok to answer your own questions on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBOutlets were not connected properly.  Once I fixed that, it works.